# Getting error zsh: permission denied: composer

Tags: php, macos, zsh

I am trying to [install Composer globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) on my mac, running macOS Monterey.

I installed php using homebrew.

```sh
╭──penguin >>=> /
╰─┤ base │ php -v
PHP 8.1.4 (cli) (built: Mar 18 2022 09:45:20) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Then, using [these](https://getcomposer.org/download/) instructions (and the ones linked at the beginning), I downloaded composer.phar and the other files into my `/usr/local/bin/composer` directory by four commands found in the first codeblock of that page.

That directory now looks like:

```
/composer
└── composer.phar
```

However, now when I attempt to use `composer -h` in the command line in any directory, I get the error `zsh: permission denied: composer`.

When I try `sudo composer -h` I get the error: `sudo: composer: command not found`

Comment: According to what you wrote, `composer` is a directory, not an executable file. BTW, it is fairly uncommon to create directories inside /usr/local/bin. This is virtually calling for troubles.

Comment: That makes sense. Is what you're saying that I should put `composer.phar` directly in `user/local/bin/` as an extension-less file? I think that is where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _extension-less file_. I personally would leave `/usr/local/bin` in the hands of the Mac updates and put executables which I install manually into an unrelated directory. This is more related to how you organize your wardrobe than a technical necessity. If I really want to access them via /usr/local/bin as well, I would then put a symlink into /usr/local/bin, i.e. `ln -s /your/install/dir/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar`.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yep, I'll post an answer now

Answer (score 5):

### The big fix:

I am pretty sure that something went wrong when I created the `/usr/local/bin/composer` directory **before** moving `composer.phar` into it.

Instead, if you just create `composer.phar` and use `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`, it will work.

### The Full solution:

Here are the exact steps I used to get it working, starting from the position I was in when I asked the question.

1. Deleted all the stuff I originally entered: /usr/local/bin/**composer**/**composer.phar**. Just a simple rm -rf command.
2. I reinstalled composer using the following:

The first Codeblock from the [Download Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) page, the command to move `composer.phar` into the path as per the [global section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) of the composer intro.

```bash
$ cd
$ cd Downloads/
$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
$ php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
Installer verified
$ php composer-setup.php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 2.3.7) successfully installed to: /Users/williamtorkington/Downloads/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

$ php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

3. Check it works (it does).

```bash
$ composer -V
Composer version 2.3.7 2022-06-06 16:43:28
```

Comment: Did you copy the description of composer on your site and say this is the correct solution?

Comment: On the official website it is mentioned to user 'sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer'
However, adding sudo gives the permission denied error. All you have to do is to remove sudo from this command and it will work fine, as explained in this answer.